# Typescript: trying to use `extends` in generics with `this` in the interface

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm using mongoose and ran into a very anoying typescript issue which I don't understand. I have extracted the problem and simplified it.

Suppose the function `model` creates `Model`s

```
interface Model<T extends Document> {}

function model<T extends Document>(): Model<T> {
    return {} as Model<T>;
}
```

I'm using this function in a `class` as follows:

```
class Collection<T extends Data> {
    private Model: Model<T>;

    constructor() {
        this.Model = model<T>();
    }

    isRecordValid(record: T): boolean {
        return record.created < new Date();
    }
}
```

It is `T extends Data` because I need to access the `created` property.
To complete the example, the `Document` and `Data` interfaces look like

```
interface Document {
    increment(): this;
}

interface Data extends Document {
    created: Date;
}
```

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/rat0hh0z/1/)

The problem is already visible in Webstorm (the red wiggle underline):

[image]

Now, when I compile this code

```
$> tsc test.ts
```

I get the following error:

```
test.ts(39,28): error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'.
  Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'Document'.
    Types of property 'increment' are incompatible.
      Type '() => Data' is not assignable to type '() => T'.
        Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

The error is caused by the line `increment(): this` or just that `this`. If you remove that line or replace `this` with `Document` the problem is gone.

In the original problem, `Document`, `model` and `Model` come from mongoose, but `Collection` is mine. Any suggestion what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite the `Document` class as follows, which is equivalent to having return type `this`, the error message becomes more clear.

```
interface Document<U extends Document<U>> {
    increment(): U;
}

interface Data extends Document<Data> {
    created: Date;
}

interface Model<T extends Document<T>> {}

function model<T extends Document<T>>(): Model<T> {
    return {} as Model<T>;
}

class Collection<T extends Data> {

    private Model: Model<T>;

    constructor() {
        this.Model = model<T>();
    }

    isRecordValid(record: T): boolean {
        return record.created < new Date();
    }
}
```

Now, at both definitions of `Model<T>` you will get the error:

```
Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<T>'.
  Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'Document<T>'.
    Types of property 'increment' are incompatible.
      Type '() => Data' is not assignable to type '() => T'.
        Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

The trace of errors from the type checker is pretty clear. As you can see, it tries to assert that `Data` is a subtype of `Document<T>`, for which to be true, it requires that `Data` be a subtype of `T`.

One way to fix it is to also make `Data` generic, something like this:

```
interface Data<T extends Data<T>> extends Document<T> {
    created: Date;
}
```

and then define the collection class as

```
class Collection<T extends Data<T>> {
   ...
}
```

**Update:**

I overlooked the fact that the `Document` type cannot be changed. As suggested in the comments by Jeanluca himself, we can solve this by using an intersection type:

```
interface Data {
    created: Date;
}

class Collection<T extends Data & Document>
```

We don't need the inheritance between `Data` and `Document` any more with this solution. Since TypeScript has structural typing system the new definition of `T extends Data & Document` means that `T` should have the properties of both `Data` and `Document`, i.e., `increment` and `created` method, which satisfies the type constraint in `model<T extends Document>()`. With a structural type system we don't need to explicitly use `extends`, it is sufficient to have the same properties.

Comment: Wow, this is complex :) Thanks. How can you create an interface and also reference it `interface Document<U extends Document<U>> { .. }`? Furthermore, the interfaces are from mongoose, I'm unsure if your suggested solution will work,

Comment: Can you also explain why `class Collection<T extends Data & Document> { ... }` does work without changing any of the interfaces?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri The types that can refer to itself or other generic types is a feature that is added in TypeScript 1.8: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5949. It is known as F-Bounded Polymorphism, and exists in other languages, such as Java.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I updated my answer. Your suggestion about using intersection type is great, and we don't need that `Data` extend `Document` anymore. The reason it works is because of the structural typing nature of TypeScript.

Comment: true, your answer makes sense. But if we use `interface Data extends Document` we should be able to do it as `class Collection<T extends Data>` It seems that generics ignore the `extends` in interfaces, right?

Comment: You mean in the original version? The problem seems to be the return type `this`. If you change `this` with `number` for example, you see the problems go away. I think with return type `this`, as it is also the case with the recursive generic version, `T` is propagated which is not what we want. So not sure if the `extends` is being ignored, it is more like `T` is being recursively propagated.

Answer (score 2):

The `T` in your `Collection<T extends Data>` class is not the same `T` in your `Model<T>()` interface.

The problem is not related to the specifics of the interfaces themselves - the issue is that, in order to be able to have an object of type `Model<TDocument>`, `TDocument` must implement the `Document` interface. You do not have such a constraint on the `T` in your `Collection` class (instead it is only constrained to implment the `Data` interface).

You could do something like this to ensure the `T` in your collection is constrained to implement *both* `Data` and `Document` interfaces:

```
interface Model<T extends Document> {}

function model<T extends Document>(): Model<T> {
    return {} as Model<T>;
}

interface DataAndDoucment extends Data, Document {

}

class Collection<T extends DataAndDoucment> {
  private Model: Model<T>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I just tried your suggestion ( [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7f6zkuh/1/) ) But I still get the exact same error. Did I implemented something incorrectly?